# Editing an answer twice in a short timespan overwrites old reasoning

Tags: support, edits

I just edit an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10912019/revisions) of mine, using "Added another possible solution" as reason.

Right after submitting (within a minute, or so) I noticed, that my addition has a typo (was missing a word), so I re-edited to fix it, using "Fixed typo" as reason.

The revision history now only shows the last reason. The previous one is somehow lost in space and now the reason doesn't match the changes at all.

There seems to be no warning that re-editing in a short timespan will update the previous revision instead of creating a new one.

Shouldn't there be at least some kind of hint that this will happen?

Comment: I think that all have priorities, and other priorities must be fixed first, that they have more practical use than this one.

Comment: you should have seen your old editing reason in the field for the reason and you chose to overwrite it.

Comment: Just edit it again and restore the reason. But I'm not convinced it's that important.

Comment: @örs: You're right, but I failed to notice it. I was hoping to have something more obvious than that.

Comment: @DaveNewton: done, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I personally quite enjoy the fact you can edit multiple posts within a short timespan like that. Often I (and others, I assume) will post an edit to a question or answer and forget to  proof read it, or notice something I missed after posting. It should not be recorded as two edits, because it was still related to the first edit. It also cuts down on revision spam. The same is true when first posting a question/answer and then immediately editing it. Just do not enter a reason when editing it immediately after saving your first edit. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Commits and Grace Periods

This is a feature. There's a 5 minute "grace period" in which edits are rolled up into a single commit. If you want your changes counted as separate commits, then just wait until the five-minute grace period expires.

#### Caveat

Be aware that each separate commit increments the counter towards [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki) status, which you may not want.

Comment: Also note that if you edit a post, then someone else edits, it, and you edit it again, all in the space of less than 5 minutes, there will be a separate revision entry for each edit.